# Re-using an existing SNS Topic in a Cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I have a SAM cloudformation template:

```
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Create SNS with a sub

Parameters:
    NotificationEmail:
        Type: String
        Description: Email address to subscribe to SNS topic

Resources:
    NotificationTopic:
        Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
        DeletionPolicy: Retain
        Properties:
            TopicName: sam-test-sns
            Subscription:
                - Endpoint: !Ref NotificationEmail
                  Protocol: email

Outputs:
    SNSTopic:
        Value: !Ref NotificationTopic
```

So I want to keep the topic **sam-test-sns** around since there are several subscribers already, and I don't want subscribers to tediously re-subscribe if I tear down the service and bring it back up.

Tearing down the service with **Retain** keeps the topic around, so that's fine. But when I try [deploy](https://github.com/kaihendry/sam-cloudtrail-ec2/blob/master/Makefile#L10) the template, it fails because it already exists.

[image: SNS already exists]

So what is the right approach to use an existing SNS topic?

Comment: How are you trying to reuse it? Same stack, different stack?

Comment: You are half way there, keep the retain parameter you put in, but then also change the SNS name so that it creates a new resource whilst leaving the existing

Comment: Re-using it in the same stack. I do not want to change the SNS name and create a new resource. I want to use the existing.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping the "Ec2NotificationTopic" resource in the template after removing the stack but keeping the topic around, will instruct CloudFormation to also create the topic when (re)creating the stack, which will always fail.

Since you are just referencing an existing topic, you should remove the resource from the template and replace the references to it with the ARN/name.

Comment: So I don't want to have to manually change the Cloudformation template.

Comment: Not at all, or just not before every deployment? If a one time change is ok, you could probably also use conditions to create a new or reference an existing resource, see this example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-sample-templates.html#w2ab1c25c28c21c47b7

Answer (score 1):

With the output done you are exporting the variable. I am going to assume you want this resource in another stack.

First you need to export the value so for example

```
Outputs:
    SNSTopic:
        Value: !Ref NotificationTopic
    Export:
        Name: Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-SNSTopic"
```

Add a parameter to your new stack of `SNSStackName`, where you would pass in the SNS stacks name (within the current region).

Then from within your new stack to reference you would need to call the output value like below:

```
Fn::ImportValue:
     Fn::Sub: "${SNSStackName}-SNSTopic"
```

Comment: I don't want it in another stack. But maybe getting the behavior I want, will demand separating it into another stack...